# Pi GPIO over network to another Pi

Tags: gpio

Can you send alarm GPIO output from Pi to another Pi GPIO input over internet?

Example: connecting door contacts to GPIO input of a Pi and play siren at remote location over internet to another Pi.

Comment: You can read the state of a GPIO pin and send it to any other computer using any of the normal protocols.

Answer (score 1):

I have made it this way:
First RPI3 read some data ( in my case temperature )and write value in file.
Second RPI3 read data from file and execute a command.
( must add permission for file reading )
or 
First RPI3 read some data ( in my case temperature )and write value in web page.
(apache server)
Second RPI3 read data from web page and execute a command.
This is all in my home network.

For direct transmission GPIO-GPOI tell someone else how to do as much as possible.